# English word to best represent the Dutch double A / [a] sound

Tags: pronunciation, translation, vowels

My Dutch name is Maarten which has a double A inside of it, pronounced simply as [a]. It is often misspelled as Marteen. I guess that most persons will remember my name as Martin but with a double vowel in there somewhere. So I often have to indicate how to write / pronounce my name.

With that in mind, I wonder what word I could best use to show how "aa" sounds like in Dutch. I've come up with "Hawaii" which I guess has two [a]'s in there. I'm wondering if there is a shorter / better word than "Hawaii" though. "Hawaii" isn't an English word after all, it's a name from another language.

Is there a short English word - borrowed or not - that has the full, high pitched [a] sound in there?

Comment: Does 'Maar' in your name rhyme with 'bath'? (*Bath* has long 'a' sound)

Comment: The three verbalisations I've listened to all pronounce 'Maarten' differently, so I don't see how this can be answered clearly.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul No, the [a] in Maarten has a higher pitch. I use Hawaii because it is almost impossible not to use the higher pitched tone for Hawaii.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not in Dutch as far as I know. So of the three, two must be wrong :) Surely every Dutch person will pronounce my name in more or less the same way (I won't get started about the rolling R in there, I can hardly pronounce it myself).

Comment: Your question is rather confusing. The 'a' sound in the word *Dutch* is /ʌ/. So if the first part of your name rhymes with *Dutch* and the second with *ten*, it's written as /mʌ(r)ten/ but if the last part rhymes with *teen*, it's written as /mʌ(r)ti:n/. If 'Maar' rhymes with *bath* and 'ten' rhymes with *ten* it's written as /mɑː(r)ten/.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul: He's talking about the sound of "aa" in words in the Dutch language that are spelled with "aa"--not in the English word "Dutch".

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul I'm talking about the 'aa' sound, my name does not rhyme with "Dutch" at all. And we pronounce "ten" at the end of the word as "tun" with the 'u' as the one in Dutch. It's a complicated language, I know. But I already explained that 'aa' sounds like the 'a''s as in Hawaii. Do you agree that that sound is different from the 'u'?

Comment: I misunderstood (I'm afraid your question is vague). Which sound of 'u'? The letter 'u' gives many sounds. Could you add IPA symbols to your question?

Comment: [{1}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwaRROF-lMA) // [{2}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTrDn4l3iIQ) // [{3}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3s7gbbb79I) (... ?)

Comment: You may have to separate all your needs. A short word is not a need, since a distinctive word (perhaps bombardment) is the one that the listener can get immediately. Spelling is easy if you emphasize that the name starts with *M double-A*. Pronunciation may be harder if *aardvark* does not help and you cannot accept a little Anglicizing of the sound to give your listener a break.

Comment: @YosefBaskin "Aardvark" is actually a pretty good one. Maybe not one I'd use when first introducing myself, and it has got two different pronunciations in there. But yeah, the first double A is perfect. I'll pick up a dictionary, see if there are any other words that start with double 'A' in there. Didn't expect that for some reason (because I used to watch the "Aardvark and the Ant" pretty often :) )

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Emma's saying {2} is clearly closest, especially when it comes to the A. It's of course missing the rolling R, but yeah. It's not high pitched enough but it is at least a bit of a prolonged sound. The other ones don't pronounce the double A at all in my opinion. Parents would correct their kids if they'd use that over here. Those pronunciations sound much more like the A in Martin if you ask me, basically they cheat and fully remove one A.

Comment: What kinds of English accents do the people you're talking to have?  The [a] sound is not found in all accents. In fact, it's rare in American English.  We don't pronounce aardvark with an [a].  We pronounce it /ˈɑɹd.vɑɹk/, which is the same vowel in Martin (/ˈmɑɹ.tɪn/)

Comment: @Juhasz Heh, this is a global world. All kinds of accents really. Most of the people I talk to are not even speaking US or UK English as their native tongue, but in that case they speak uh, Movie English I suppose. Which is why Hawaii might still be the best word. Especially the second A gets prolonged almost automatically, and the following double I generally raises the pitch .

Comment: @Juhasz Note that "Aardvark" is Dutch in origin (mud + pig) although we use the full word "varken" - "vark" is taken from the South African language; I see it change to "Ardvark" in the future, if the current dictionaries and such allow it to. Spelling has become much more static after all.